# <s:select> with optgroup in Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, optgroup, struts1, struts-tags

I am working on a task of migrating existing Struts1 application to Struts2. I am stuck in the problem. Within an `<s:select>` I need to categories the options with `<optgroup>`. The following code would do this in Struts1. How can I achieve this with Struts2?

```xml
<html:select id="foodList" property="foodItemId" onclick="selectRadio('0')">
    <c:if test="${not empty foodList1}">
        <optgroup label="Risk Analysis Report Sets">
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${foodList1}">
                <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </optgroup>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty foodList2}">
        <optgroup label="NMX Report Sets">
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${foodList2}">
                <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </optgroup>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty foodList3}">
        <optgroup label="Standard Report Sets">
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${list3}">
                <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </optgroup>
    </c:if>
</html:select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<s:optgroup/>` is your friend here.

From [Struts2 JavaDoc](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/OptGroup.html):

> **org.apache.struts2.components**
>
> ## Class OptGroup
>
> Create a optgroup component which needs to resides within a select
>   tag.
>
> This component is to be used within a Select component.
>
> ```xml
> <s:select label = "My Selection"
>            name = "mySelection"
>           value = "%{'POPEYE'}"
>            list = "%{#{'SUPERMAN':'Superman', 'SPIDERMAN':'spiderman'}}">
>
>     <s:optgroup label = "Adult"
>                  list = "%{#{'SOUTH_PARK':'South Park'}}" />
>     <s:optgroup label = "Japanese"
>                  list = "%{#{'POKEMON':'pokemon','DIGIMON':'digimon'}}" />
> </s:select>
> ```